# Performance of HtmlHelper vs Razor Helper (@helper)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper, razor-declarative-helpers

I understand that there are different ways to render reusable HTML snippets in ASP.NET MVC.  Here are two possibilities that people generally refer as a "helper" approach:

1. HtmlHelper Extension Methods
2. Razor Helper Methods (e.g. `@helper functionName() { }` )

**Which performs faster?**

NOTE: I already know that the performance of an HtmlHelper is faster than a Partial View.  But, my question is about comparing the performance of HtmlHelper -vs- Razor Helper (e.g. @helper syntax)

Comment: Do you expect helper methods to be the slowest part of your application?

Comment: I believe they will be compiled into similar code when the view is built. Anecdotally, route resolution and metadata traversal are usually visible as expensive (relatively speaking) when I profile an MVC application. These things shouldn't be impacted by how the helper is declared.